# Error "int1" is not convertible to 'Bool' swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

Im' quite new at swift and for my project I need to use swift3 and xcode8.1
I tried differents solutions, but noting works.
I think it's because of the swift3 from swift2 conversion as I can see on differents topics. Nevertheless that didn't help me a lot.

Here is my function:

```
func startHeartRateUpdates() {
    output("Starting Heart Rate updates...")
    if let client = self.client {
        do {
            try client.sensorManager.startHeartRateUpdates(to: nil, withHandler: { (heartRateData: MSBSensorHeartRateData!, error: NSError!) in
                self.hrLabel.text = NSString(format: "Heart Rate: %3u %@",
                    heartRateData.heartRate,
                    heartRateData.quality == MSBSensorHeartRateQuality.acquiring ? "Acquiring" : "Locked") as String
            })
            self.perform(#selector(ViewController.stopHeartRateUpdates), with: nil, afterDelay: 60)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            output("startHeartRateUpdatesToQueue failed: \(error.description)")
        }
    } else {
        output("Client not connected, can not start heart rate updates")
    }
}
```

And the only error I had is this 2 lines undernlined in red:

```
heartRateData.quality == MSBSensorHeartRateQuality.acquiring ? "Acquiring" : "Locked") as String
```

With the message:

> 'Int1' is not convertible to 'Bool'

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show the property var for `MSBSensorHeartRateQuality`?  `Int1` is not a type in Swift, b.t.w.  I suspect you simply have a typo in your declaration.

Comment: I've no property var for this.
Or I'm not sure to understand your question.. Sorry Im not english native

Answer (score 1):

I think the field `acquiring` is an `int` type. If you use `int` type in condional statement as a condion you should use `==`.

**Example:**

```
heartRateData.quality = MSBSensorHeartRateQuality.acquiring == 1 ? "Acquiring" : "Locked") as String
```

Comment: He thanks for your answer.

But I'v 2 others errors when I try this:  
"Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'Comparison Precedence'"  

"Binary operator '=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and 'Int"
I will try to check it though

Comment: I tried it. Then I got the error:  "Cannot assign to property:'quality' is a get-only property.